# Docker - traffic mirroring

Tags: docker

I have 2 different running containers.
I'd like to be able to mirror traffic that comes to container #1 into container #2.

Is there a docker command for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "mirror traffic"? Traffic mirroring is normally done on a lower network level than where docker container operate. Perhaps you meant "load balance traffic"?

Answer (score 6):

Traffic mirroring is possible on linux interfaces, I don't believe docker provides a method for setting that up though. The mirroring should work via the `veth` interfaces docker sets up for each container, if you add it manually.

#### Traffic Control

`tc` allows you to manage traffic in a number of ways, normally used for quality of service type queuing. `tc` also provides a `mirror` action. The [following](https://serverfault.com/a/686612) matches all inbound and outbound traffic and mirrors it to another interface.

```
tc qdisc add dev vethb692b75@if13 ingress
tc filter add dev vethb692b75@if13 parent ffff: \
   protocol all prio 2 u32 \
   match u32 0 0 flowid 1:1 \
   action mirred egress mirror dev veth4305fdd@if15

tc qdisc replace dev vethb692b75@if13 parent root handle 10: prio
tc filter add dev vethb692b75@if13 parent 10: \
   protocol all prio 2 u32 \
   match u32 0 0 flowid 10:1 \
   action mirred egress mirror dev veth4305fdd@if15
```

#### IP Tables

`iptables` can forward cloned packets to a routable host. This would normally be used to mirror traffic to an external host.

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i vethb692b75@if13 -j TEE --gateway <monitor_ip>
iptables -t mangle –I POSTROUTING -i vethb692b75@if13 -j TEE --gateway <monitor_ip>
```

#### tcpdump

As most network monitoring software in the linux world deals in tcpdump, you may also be able to tcpdump the interface from the host into a fifo that is mounted into your monitoring container.

```
mkfifo /tmp/remotecapture.fifo 
tcpdump -s 0 -n -w - -U -i vethb692b75@if13 > /tmp/remotecapture.fifo
docker run -v /tmp/remotecapture.fifo:/tmp/remotecapture.fifo <image> netmonitor -f /tmp/remotecapture.fifo
```

#### Notes

The `veth` names are assigned to each container startup so capturing would need to be part of your container start/stop process. You want to remove any rules on a container stop.

In the cases where traffic is forwarded somewhere, the recipient container/host should not be routing any of these packets back or to their original destination.

Comment: That could be a better fit (than my answer), considering the OP's question. +1

Comment: Thanks!! that was very useful.  Another question please, how can I get the bridge name given the name of the container?

Comment: @EfratLevy submit that as another question.

Answer (score 2):

If would be easier to setup container#2 as a reverse proxy for container#1

That means container#2 see all traffic and send it to container#1

You can use as container#2 [`traefik.io/`](https://traefik.io/). It is meant for load balancing, but in your case, you could define only one backend (so no load balancing there) referencing container#1.
You can build a traefik container quite easily ([see this Dockerfile](https://github.com/hypriot/rpi-traefik/blob/master/Dockerfile) for instance, for arm architecture)

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't like container #2 to set as a reverse proxy because this means that if it fails, then the main container does not get any traffic  \=

Is there another solution?

Comment: @EfratLevy you could install traefik directly in container#1 and send traffic to your container#1 main server, and to container#2

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: In case you are dealing with HTTP traffic only**

You can run Nginx in a 3rd container and use that the entry point for docker containers. Then use the nginx as a reverse proxy for Container 1 and use nginx mirror directive to mirror all requests to container 2 as well.

Effectively, container 1 will receive all the requests and send responses. Container 2 will also get the requests but its responses would not be sent back to the user/client that made the request.

Here's a sample Nginx Config.

```
upstream logger {
    server app2:3002;
}

upstream app {
    server app1:3002;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    location / {
        mirror /mirror;
        mirror_request_body on;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }
    location  = /mirror {
        internal;
        proxy_connect_timeout 200ms;
        proxy_read_timeout 200ms;
        proxy_pass http://logger$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-FOR $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Comment: But it can be UDP traffic - not HTTP(S).

Comment: @Dmytro yea, this would work only for HTTP(s), I'd follow matt's answer for TCP